# How will I know when to increase the size of my RDS instance. Using Postgres with django

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-rds

How will I know when to increase the size of my RDS instance (vertical scaling). Using Postgres with django. Suppose I choose t2 micro to start how will I know when to increase its size. I am using a django Application using PostgreSQL and Amazon t2micro instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS [Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.UsingMetrics)
 provides what you need. You can monitor your RDS performance.

Also, you can log all slow queries by setting [log_min_duration_statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT)